# Warning message "AcroPDF.dll" when I try to display a PDF document within the web browser

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

In Internet Explorer 11, when I click a link to a PDF file to display it within the browser, I always get this following message :

[image]

*adobe.com* being the only value changing, depending on which website the PDF file is.

Pressing "OK" shows the document in browser.

How could I disable this warning ?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall Acrobat Pro since upgrading to Windows 8.1

Comment: Hi ! I did a fresh install of Windows 8.1, not an upgrade from Windows 8.

Comment: Doesn't really matter if you installed the update or did a fresh install to be honest.  I highly suspect this to be an issue Adobe has to address.  What version of Acrobat do you have installed?

Comment: Well, I thought it matters because you asked if I tried to reinstall since I upgraded... but here it's a fresh install of both the OS and the software. And I don't have Acrobat Pro, only Adobe Reader 11.0.5. Thanks for your help.

Comment: All I wanted to know is if you attempted to reinstall Adobe Acrobat/Adobe Reader.  I personally have the same problem which indicates to me this is an Adobe compatibility problem with IE11

Comment: Well at least I'm not alone :-) thanks again for helping me, I hope there will be a fix soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution !

Go under *Tools* -> *Internet Settings* -> *Advanced* tab, and check *Enable 64-bit processes for Enhanced Protected Mode*. Then restart IE and voila, no more warnings !

[image]