# How can I undo "always ignore" blocking PDF in IE10?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-reader, internet-explorer-10

The problem experienced by the user [here](https://superuser.com/questions/663949/warning-message-acropdf-dll-when-i-try-to-display-a-pdf-document-within-the-we) is similar to what I get in that I receive a prompt: "This webpage wants to run 'AcroPDF.dll'. If you trust this site, you can disable Enhanced Protected Mode for this site to run the control."
[image: IE10 AcroPDF.dll EPM error]

I understand the prompt can be removed by by disabling EPM but my major concern is actually how to view a PDF when the "Always ignore" button has been clicked. I haven't been able to find a way to undo this and a couple of users have accidentally selected the option since IE 10 was rolled out.
When a user clicks on a PDF after the "Always ignore" button has been checked for that website they only ever see a black box with a cross.

[image: missing pdf after clicking "Always ignore" in IE10]

Tried so far:

- Uninstalled & reinstalled IE10
- Checked for entries in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Safety
- Performed a repair on Adobe Reader from the menu options.
- Completely reinstalled Adobe Reader
- Deleted temporary internet files
- Disabled EPM after the pdf had been ignored.

Comment: What version of Adobe Reader do you have installed? Adobe Acrobat XI does not have this problem.

Comment: I should have included that information, sorry. The Adobe Version is 11.0.0.379

Comment: I can't find a conclusive answer on if uninstalling IE10 deletes browsing history, so on the off chance it doesn't, have you tried Ctrl+Shift+Del (Tools -> Delete browsing history) with "History" checked and see if that brings back the EPM "Disable" and "Always Ignore" buttons?

Comment: Panhandel solved it. I didn't have any option to delete browsing history as it's denied within group policy. I created a new GPO and deleted everything and the prompt came back when I revisited the failing site. Do you want to copy your comment to the answer section?

Comment: @Mokilok will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think uninstalling IE10 deletes browsing history, so as a test, can you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> (Tools -> Delete browsing history) with "History" checked and see if that brings back the EPM "Disable" and "Always Ignore" buttons?

Answer (score -1):

- Create a system restore point
- search your computer to find the `acropdf.dll` file if it is not on your hard drive you may need to download from a site.
- Copy or Save the file to the following location on your system: `C://Windows//System32`
- Confirm the replacement of the old, damaged `acropdf.dll` file.
- Register the File
- Click the Windows logo in the bottom, left corner of the screen.
- Type `cmd` in the *Search* field if you are using Vista or Windows 7. Click *Run* and type `cmd` in the *Open* field if you are using Windows 7. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This opens the Command Prompt.
- Type the following command in the prompt:

  `Regsvr32 acropdf.dll`

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to register the file. Exit the Command Prompt and restart your system.